# Insert an image in a labelFrame title with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wonder if it's possible to insert an image or icon in the title of a Labelframe in tkinter ?

Maybe something like this `lf = Labelframe(root, image='my_img')`, the same as we can do with a button.
It would be very useful.

Comment: Create a `Label` with image, then use `labelwidget` option of `LabelFrame` to use the label instead of a text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert any widget as **labelwidget** option of LabelFrame.

If you want an image instead of text displayed in LabelFrame:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

w = tk.Tk()
w.geometry("400x500")
img_open = Image.open("example_1.png")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_open)

label_title = tk.Label(w, image=img)    #important Do Not grid/pack/place it!

label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(w, labelwidget=label_title)
label_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

#fill LabelFrame with something to make it visible
bt = tk.Button(label_frame, text="Press")
bt.grid(padx=20, pady=20)
w.mainloop()
```

Output:
[image]

Or like I said before you can use any widget.
An example label with image and a label with text.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

w = tk.Tk()
w.geometry("400x500")
img_open = Image.open("example_1.png")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_open)

frame_labelwidget = tk.Frame(w)    #important Do Not grid/pack/place it!

label_image = tk.Label(frame_labelwidget, image=img)
label_image.grid(row=0, column=0)

label_text = tk.Label(frame_labelwidget, text="Teamwork")
label_text.grid(row=0, column=1)

label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(w, labelwidget=frame_labelwidget)
label_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

#fill LabelFrame with something to make it visible
bt = tk.Button(label_frame, text="Press")
bt.grid(padx=20, pady=20)
w.mainloop()
```

Output: [image]

Of course that makes less sense because you can have text and an image combined in tk.Label by using compound option.
I added it only for demonstration purpose, you can add any widget you want. Instead of label_text you could add an Entry, Canvas...

Comment: A label can have both image and text.  Don't need to create two labels for image and text.

Comment: You're right it is just for demonstration purpose it could be any widget.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I wanted, but for me it doesn't works to add an image and a text in the same label (I need to create two labels for image and text)

Comment: You need to add compound option like this one: **label_image = tk.Label(frame_labelwidget, image=img, text="Teamwork", compound=tk.LEFT)**